# Como escolher qual campo serializar - Jackson

Tags: java, json, java-ee, jackson

Estou usando **Jackson** para converter meus objetos em **Json**. 
Os campos que não quero serializar marco com a anotação @JsonIgnore, mas em alguns casos queria poder serializar esses campos. Existe alguma maneira de escolher quando serializa-los?

Comment: Não dá pra saber todo o contexto, mas parece que o mais viável para você aqui é usar `JsonView`, então em cada caso usa uma. Por exemplo, é muito comum serializar pouca coisa em listagem (uma view para isso) e mais dados no cadastro/edição (outra view para isto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem duas alternativas:

1 - Você cria classes para representar as informações que devem ser serializadas para cada caso e popula essas classes de acordo com a necessidade.

2 - Você pode criar um serializador customizado que implementa a interface `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer`, registrar esse serializador no seu `ObjectMapper` e fazer a serialização programaticamente de acordo com a necessidade.